# Data Binding on a UserControl - WPF, MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm trying to understand how to bind data from a ViewModel to a `UserControl` using MVVM in WPF.  I'm following [this example here](https://medium.com/@mpcodes/wpf-c-mvvm-sample-application-14ffe10b5bf2), but when clicking the Login button, no message appears and the function is not hit when I set a breakpoint.  I set the `DataContext` in the `UserControl` to the `LoginVM` class, but still the function is not called and the message box does not show. Where is this program going wrong?  Here is the program:

**App.xaml**

```
<Application x:Class="TestWpfMvvm.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestWpfMvvm">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/Resources/MainWindowResources.xaml" />
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**App.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class App : Application
    {
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnStartup(e);
            MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
            MainWindowViewModel mainWindow = new MainWindowViewModel();
            window.DataContext = mainWindow;
            window.Show();
        }
    }
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="TestWpfMvvm.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestWpfMvvm"
        xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:TestWpfMvvm.UserControls"
        xmlns:view="clr-namespace:TestWpfMvvm.Views"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <view:LoginView />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**LoginView.xaml** <-- From the [website](https://medium.com/@mpcodes/wpf-c-mvvm-sample-application-14ffe10b5bf2) sample

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestWpfMvvm.Views.LoginView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestWpfMvvm.Views"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:TestWpfMvvm.ViewModel"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
             DataContext="vm:LoginVM">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"
                    Margin="50">
        <TextBlock Text="Login" 
                       FontSize="25"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalAlignment="Top"
                       FontWeight="Bold"
                       Padding="10"
                       />
        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center"
              HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="User Name" 
                   Grid.Row="0"
                   Margin="0,15"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <TextBox  Grid.Column="1"
                  Grid.Row="1"
                  Padding="0,5"
                  Width="255"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  Text="{Binding UserName, Mode=TwoWay,
                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Password" 
                   Grid.Row="2"
                   Margin="0,15"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="3"
                      Text="{Binding Password, Mode=TwoWay, 
                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                      Padding="0,5"                           
                      Width="255"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        </Grid>
        <Button x:Name="LoginBtn" 
                    Content="Login" 
                    Foreground="White"
                    Background="Black"
                    Margin="0,25"
                    Command="{Binding LoginCommand}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding UserName}"
                    Height="35"
                    Width="250"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

**LoginVM.cs** <-- Inherits from `ViewModelBase.cs` which implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

```
using System.Windows.Input;
using TestWpfMvvm.Model;
using TestWpfMvvm.Utis;

namespace TestWpfMvvm.ViewModel
{
    public class LoginVM : ViewModelBase
    {
        private User user;
        public ICommand LoginCommand { get { return new RelayCommand(LoggedIn); } }
        public LoginVM()
        {
            user = new User();
        }

        public string UserName
        {
            get => user.UserName;
            set
            {
                user.UserName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(UserName));
            }
        }

        public string Password
        {
            get => user.Password;
            set
            {
                user.Password = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Password));
            }
        }

        private void LoggedIn(object parameter)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"Logged in successful as {parameter}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `DataContext="vm:LoginVM"` set the string `"vm:LoginVM"` as DataContext, certainly not what you want. In general, a UserControl (as any other control) should never explicity sets its own DataContext. Just remove that assignment.

Comment: @Clemens I removed that line, but it did not solve the issue.  The command is still not being called.  How do you set the data context of a UserControl?  If I had 4 UserControls that were being placed on the MainWindow and I wanted a different class to be the DataContext of each, how would this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out.

In my MainWindow.xaml I had to change

`<view:LoginView />` to `<view:LoginView DataContext={Binding LoginViewModel} />`

And in the `MainWindowViewModel.cs` I had to add a `LoginViewModel` property of type `LoginVM` and initialize it.